# struct producing errors in C

Tags: c, struct

I am getting strange compilation errors from trying to create a struct in C.

Here is my code:

```
#define ALIGNMENT 8

/* rounds up to the nearest multiple of ALIGNMENT */
#define ALIGN(size) (((size) + (ALIGNMENT-1)) & ~0x7)

#define SIZE_T_SIZE (ALIGN(sizeof(size_t)))

#define BLK_HDR_SIZE ALIGN(sizeof(blockHdr))


typdef struct header {
    size_t size;
    blockHdr *next_p;
    blockHdr *prior_p;
} blockHdr;
```

This is the error message:

```
 mm.c:49:8: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘struct’
 typdef struct header {
        ^
make: *** [mm.o] Error 1
```

I am baffled by this error. Is there something wrong with my code, or is there a more serious issue?

Comment: Look at the order of your typedef declaration and your variable declaration. You also have a typo in `typdef`

Comment: `typdef`? Is it a typo in this question or in your original code?

Comment: @YuHao Wow I made a dumb mistake.

Comment: I sat there and stared at this for half an hour and dug into various places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in `typdef`.  Next, you'll get an error about `blockHdr` not being defined.

The correct definition is:

```
typedef struct header {
    size_t size;
    struct header *next_p;
    struct header *prior_p;
} blockHdr;
```

You can't use the `typedef` before it is declared.  You have to use the actual structure name.

Answer (score 1):

I think that that instead of

typdef struct header

it should be

typedef struct header

Comment: He's going to have another problem after that